# Solutions for Error: "The Datasheet view is attempting to retrieve data from a different domain"?

Tags: 2007, data-view-web-part, error, datasheet

A couple users of our SP2007 site have received this error while accessing datasheet views.  They are able to view/edit lists in 'standard view' without any issues and their PCs are configured with XP / IE8.

What is the cause of this error and are there any solutions?

Comment: Could be any number of things, but it usually points to a problem with alternate access mappings. Is there anything in common with your problem users that your other users don't share (DNS settings, for example)? Are you load balancing your WFEs?

Answer (score 4):

This issue will sometimes pop up if you commonly access your pages with two urls, i.e. http://mysite.company.com and http://machinename.  Verify that the user is accessing the site using the URL specified as the primary address for that zone in Alternate Access Mappings.

If you are using the http://machinename url convention, I would *strongly* recommend that you move away from that as it will cause you trouble down the road, i.e. when you need to move to a new machine or when you need to host a new web app on port 80.